# Installing SQL 2005 Management Studio (Not express edition)

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have the SQL Server 2005 Developer Edition DVD.

I have been trying to install SQL 2005 Management Studio for a couple hours, but it isn't working.

Are there any known bugs on this issue?

Comment: Apparently so. Try [this link to someone's blog who gives a workaround](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/name/archive/2007/09/24/Installing-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-with-SQL-Server.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you select the feature in the "Features" screen?  On occasion you need to explicitly select it.  Try running the installer again and selecting the feature.

Answer (score 0):

you might be having Express edition installed on your system. 
To install Full Editoin SQL server  you need to uninstall it simply 
and just rename the sql server folder in program files before installing 
Sql server 2005,